# VBA Cutting off String?

Tags: vba, excel

I openly admit I know nothing about vba..

I am working on a legacy tool for a project and its written in VBA. There is a bug I am working on and I have narrowed down the issue but unable to figure out why my string is apparently being cutoff?

```
 strXPlusLast4 = "xxxxxxxxxxxx" & strDCLast4
    For Each varItem In objIE.Document.getElementsByTagName("tr")
        If InStr(varItem.innerhtml, strXPlusLast4) Then
            strDCStatus = Replace(Split(Split(varItem.innerhtml, "<TD>")(3), "</TD>")(0), "&nbsp;", "")
```

Using an IE object to navigate to a page, it is looking through the all of the `tr`. Within the `tr`'s that it finds, it is looking to see if a string exists.

If it finds this string, it goes into the `IF statement` which is where I am stuck.

Once here, I check the value of the `varitem.innerHTML` and it is getting cutoff around 250 characters, right in the middle of the actual row data.

I am trying to just find out if there is any limitation as to why the value of `innerHTML` is not the full `HTML` content I expect to see that I am looking at on the web page it is scraping.

This data is also cutoff when I add `varItem` to my watches and look at the `innerHTML` of the object.

Can anyone shed any light on the little bit of code I am able to post around this issue? My root problem is that I am not getting the `strDCStatus` I would expect because it is not searching the full row of data as something is getting cutoff.

**Update**

Here is the best I can provide for the `TR` that this is looking within:

```
<tr class="">
  <td>
    &nbsp;
  </td>
  <td>2 Blah Blah &nbsp;</td>
  <td class="AccountNumber">
    xxxxxxxxxxxx1234 &nbsp;&nbsp;
    <a href="#" onclick="view(this, event,'12345', '45678');return false" class=""><img src="https://MySite" title="Click to Expand" alt="!"></a>
    &nbsp;
  </td>
  <td>Closed&nbsp;</td>
  <td>Jan 1, 2011&nbsp;</td>
  <td>Nov 30, 2011&nbsp;</td>
  <td>N/A&nbsp;</td>
  <td>
    xx/xxxx &nbsp;&nbsp;
    <a href="#" onclick="view(this, event,'12345', '56789'); return false;" class=""><img src="https://MySite" title="Click to Expand"></a>
    &nbsp;
  </td>
</tr>
```

It is using the `innerHTML` so everything between the `<tr>` tags. it is getting cut off around the `onClick` HTML data.

The status I will eventually try and get is "Closed" in the 4th `td` but I haven't been able to attempt that since I don't appear to have a full row html to look through.

Comment: This isn't a [mcve]. At the very least it would help if you give an example of a string `varItem.innerhtml` that is "getting cut off" together with the intended value of `strDCStatus` after that statement is executed.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken string length is limited to 255 chars but there are ways around.  Just search SO.

Comment: @mrbungle If you are referring to VBA strings, you are mistaken. Typing `?len(string(10^6,"*"))` in the immediate window instantly prints `1000000` rather than throwing an error.

Comment: @JohnColeman Updated with a snippet of code its looking through.

Comment: `Split` is case sensitive and `<td>` isn't `<TD>`

Comment: How are you checking the value of `varItem.innerhtml`? What you are seeing might be an artifact of your checking. What happens if you insert the line `Debug.Print Len(varItem.innerhtml)`?

Comment: I added the var to my watch list and then copied the value from there into notepad and saw it cutoff.

Comment: The debugging tool will only show you a part of a long string (perhaps even ending with `...`).

Comment: Good to know, the ellipses don't show up but surprisingly, the case sensitivity you mentioned fixed my issue. There was nothing wrong with the code, the HTML tags case just changed on the source page which caused this whole mess. Thanks you for the mini-lesson :)

Comment: I added it as an answer just in case someone else gets misled by the watches window and searches for a solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `Watches` window only shows a portion of a long string (although, unlike the `Locals` window, it doesn't indicate this with a terminating `...`).

For example, when I put a watch on the variable `t` in:

```
Sub test()
    Dim s As String, t As String
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 0 To 9
        s = s & String(50, CStr(i))
    Next i
    t = s
End Sub
```

and then copy-paste the value into notepad I see:

```
"0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000011111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222223333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333344444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444
```

even though the string is clearly much longer.

The real bug in the code itself is likely due to the case-sensitivity of strings in `Split` and the resulting fact that the delimiter `<td>` differs from the delimiter `<TD>`